# How to use other class files effectively?

Tags: performance, class

When does a good programmer know to make a new class file in their games/applications? I've made some small(ish) games and applications with up to 20,000 lines of code in just 1 class file - is this bad practice? The games/applications I make run just fun for what they do and throughout development I've failed to find a reason to make any new class files.

Could I potentially make a fully fledged video game with 100,000+ lines of code in just 1 class file?

In terms of programming languages, I frequently use C# but I've found myself testing about in Java, C++, and Python, always stuck at the same problem. I read through all sorts of source code that has *hundreds* of class files with just a few lines of code in them - I never understand the point?

Comment: To answer your question, there is a mantra that classes should have [**one job**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), if you have one class that takes 20,000 lines of code, it is likely doing too much work, and should be divided into separate classes.

Comment: Try looking at the code of an open-source game.

Answer (score 1):

> I've made some small(ish) games and applications with up to 20,000 lines of code in just 1 class file - is this bad practice?

Yes. Have a look at the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

> Could I potentially make a fully fledged video game with 100,000+ lines of code in just 1 class file?

You could. Good luck with maintaining it with any reasonable results though.

> I read through all sorts of source code that has hundreds of class files with just a few lines of code in them - I never understand the point?

Usually, classes should do one thing, do it completely and do it well. This stops areas of functionality from being replicated all over the code, centralizes algorithms, data and dependencies. This in turn decreases code duplication and increases code modularity and reuse.

Code modularity leads to reusable code, and easier extensions of existing functionality.

See [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles for details.

Answer (score 0):

The point of using classes, and Object Oriented Programming in general, is to make it more intuitive for yourself as a programmer, and to make it easier to keep control of data as it flows through your program.

Classes are often modeled on real-world categories of things, and basically are a bunch of data coupled with *all* the behaviour that you would expect from this data.

Using classes involves a new perspective on how the program is constructed altogether, shifting focus from what you want the program to do to what you want it to do those things to. Thinking this way will naturally lead you to create a well-organized set of classes that each perform well-defined operations on a well-defined set of data.

More tangibly, if you have a 100000+ - line class and you discover a bug, tracing out exactly what is causing it will be a much more complicated affair than if you could localize it to a single class of a few lines.